# jQuery ajax POST call to codebehind method returns XHR status 0

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call the method in the aspx.cs from the aspx page by creating an ajax call. However the response is 0. Some research lead me to verify datatypes and data in the ajax call, but none of that resolved the issue.Could there be a window losing focus which might be resulting in the call being UNSENT?

```
<script>
        function blah(e) {
        var url = 'Default.aspx/Test';

        selectedFiles = document.getElementById("MainContent_file1");
        var file = selectedFiles.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {

            var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(reader.result, '12345');
            encrypted = encodeURIComponent(encrypted);
            var encryptedFile = new File([encrypted], file.name + '.encrypted', { type: "text/plain", lastModified: new Date() });

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('myFile', encryptedFile)
            //data.append('file[0]', encryptedFile);
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {'aa': encryptedFile},
                //data: encrypted,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                url: "Default.aspx/Test",
                success: function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(xhr.statusText);

                }
            });
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }

</script>
```

ASPX.CS

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Test(object aa)
    {
       return "Hello";
    }
```

Error message:

```
xhr = Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}, textStatus = "error", error = ""
```

Detailed Response: Default.aspx:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:51936/Default.aspx
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK 
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:6169
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 09 Dec 2016 16:15:52 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

Test:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:51936/Default.aspx/Test
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:51936
Referer:http://localhost:51936/Default.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: You may want to try monitoring / debugging it with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4)  I suspect there might be an HTTP error that would give you a hint.

Comment: Open the developer console and run the function on the page. In the **Network** tab, you should see the request go through. From there, you can view both the Headers that were sent *to* the code-behind, the *Response* returned from the function, and/or any errors that were encountered.

Comment: Updated question with output from dev console

Comment: Suggest using web crypto an not CryptoJS. Also you should maybe want to encrypt the arraybuffer and not the dataURL

Comment: https://infotechinc.github.io/symmetric-encryption-in-browser/